# MySQL Workbench error for schema in database and table created from Workbench itself

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Based on a database with a single simple table, created using MySQL Workbench (Community) version 6.3.7b1199-CE-64b connected to CentOS MySQL 5.1.73, I tried to use MySQL workbench to get information for the database (clicking "i" next to database name), but I get the following error windows.

[image: MySQL Error 1]
[image: MySQL Error 2]
[image: MySQL Error 3]
[image: MySQL Error 4]

What can be the problem?

After running `mysql_upgrade` a new error appeared as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to most of your Error Message, the problem is from sandbox_02,

> expected 20 found 16

Foreing keys must be respected, if it`s the case here, you are just missing some important rows.

Run mySQL_upgrade, to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, after running `mysql_upgrade` command I got another error, as updated in the question.